# assign variable based on starting/ending pattern

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, grouping, data-manipulation

I have this dataset:

```
a <- data.frame("session_id" = c(rep(1,10), rep(2,7), rep(3,2)),
                "content" = c("A", "B", "C","open", "A", "J", "M", "K","exit", "D", 
                "open", "U", "T","quit", "I", "M" , "A", "Q", "M" ), 
            "type" = c("non-edit", "non-edit", "non-edit", "edit", "edit", "edit", 
            "edit", "edit", "edit", "non-edit", "edit", "edit", "edit", 
            "edit", "non-edit", "non-edit", "non-edit", "non-edit", "non-edit"))
```

I want to have the type column be assigned to either "non-edit" or "edit" type based on the content column. The type would be "edit" when we detect "open" in the content until "exit" or "quit". You can see the example in the example I provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We create a new column (`new_type`) and initialise the values to "non-edit". We then find indices for occurrence of "open" and "quit" and create a sequence of indices between them using `mapply` and replace the corresponding values to "edit"

```
a$new_type <- "non-edit"
open_ind <- which(a$content == "open")
close_ind <- which(a$content %in% c("quit", "exit"))
a$new_type[unlist(mapply(":", open_ind, close_ind))] <- "edit"


a
#   session_id content     type new_type
#1           1       A non-edit non-edit
#2           1       B non-edit non-edit
#3           1       C non-edit non-edit
#4           1    open     edit     edit
#5           1       A     edit     edit
#6           1       J     edit     edit
#7           1       M     edit     edit
#8           1       K     edit     edit
#9           1    exit     edit     edit
#10          1       D non-edit non-edit
#11          2    open     edit     edit
#12          2       U     edit     edit
#13          2       T     edit     edit
#14          2    quit     edit     edit
#15          2       I non-edit non-edit
#16          2       M non-edit non-edit
#17          2       A non-edit non-edit
#18          3       Q non-edit non-edit
#19          3       M non-edit non-edit
```

To understand the steps,

```
open_ind
#[1]  4 11
close_ind
#[1]  9 14
unlist(mapply(":", open_ind, close_ind))
#[1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 11 12 13 14
```

Answer (score 2):

After grouping by 'session_id', create another group by taking the cumulative sum of logical expressions and use that to assing values 'edit' and 'non-edit'

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% 
  group_by(session_id) %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum((content == "open")|
     lag(content %in% c("exit", "quit"), 
              default = first(content))), add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(type1 = case_when(any(content %in% c("open", "exit", "quit")) ~ "edit", 
                         TRUE ~ "non-edit")) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp)
# A tibble: 19 x 4
#   session_id content type     type1   
#        <dbl> <fct>   <fct>    <chr>   
# 1          1 A       non-edit non-edit
# 2          1 B       non-edit non-edit
# 3          1 C       non-edit non-edit
# 4          1 open    edit     edit    
# 5          1 A       edit     edit    
# 6          1 J       edit     edit    
# 7          1 M       edit     edit    
# 8          1 K       edit     edit    
# 9          1 exit    edit     edit    
#10          1 D       non-edit non-edit
#11          2 open    edit     edit    
#12          2 U       edit     edit    
#13          2 T       edit     edit    
#14          2 quit    edit     edit    
#15          2 I       non-edit non-edit
#16          2 M       non-edit non-edit
#17          2 A       non-edit non-edit
#18          3 Q       non-edit non-edit
#19          3 M       non-edit non-edit
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pipeline that doesn't need grouping.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

b <- 
    a %>% 
    # 1. Mark the boundaries of the 'edit' regions.
    mutate(type = case_when(content == "open"           ~ "edit", 
                            grepl("exit|quit", content) ~ "non-edit",
                                                   TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>%
    # 2. Fill the NAs with the last good value. 'open' down to 'exit/quit'
    #    will be filled with 'edit'.
    tidyr::fill(type) %>%
    # 3. Replace unfilled NAs, like at the top of the table.
    replace_na(list(type = "non-edit")) %>%
    # 4. Rename the exit/quit boundary.
    mutate(type = ifelse(grepl("exit|quit", content), "edit", type))

b

#>    session_id content     type
#> 1           1       A non-edit
#> 2           1       B non-edit
#> 3           1       C non-edit
#> 4           1    open     edit
#> 5           1       A     edit
#> 6           1       J     edit
#> 7           1       M     edit
#> 8           1       K     edit
#> 9           1    exit     edit
#> 10          1       D non-edit
#> 11          2    open     edit
#> 12          2       U     edit
#> 13          2       T     edit
#> 14          2    quit     edit
#> 15          2       I non-edit
#> 16          2       M non-edit
#> 17          2       A non-edit
#> 18          3       Q non-edit
#> 19          3       M non-edit
```

Answer (score 0):

Plan: Step through the rows looking for 'transition keys' in the content column. If key is 'open' act immediately, if 'quit' or 'exit' act on next row. 
Consider the following code to implement:

```
last  <-  'exit'  #initialize last
keys <- c('open','exit','quit')  #transition keys
for (i in 1:nrow(a)) {
a$type[i]  <-  ifelse(a$content[i] %in% keys, 'edit', 
ifelse(last=='open','edit','non-edit'))
last  <- ifelse(a$content[i]%in% keys, a$content[i],last)
}
a
R> a
   session_id content     type
1           1       A non-edit
2           1       B non-edit
3           1       C non-edit
4           1    open     edit
5           1       A     edit
6           1       J     edit
7           1       M     edit
8           1       K     edit
9           1    exit     edit
10          1       D non-edit
11          2    open     edit
12          2       U     edit
13          2       T     edit
14          2    quit     edit
15          2       I non-edit
16          2       M non-edit
17          2       A non-edit
18          3       Q non-edit
19          3       M non-edit
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way in base R using `cumsum`:

```
a$new_type <- c("non-edit","edit")[
  cumsum(a$content=="open") - c(0,head(cumsum(a$content %in% c("exit","quit")),-1)) +1]
#    session_id content     type new_type
# 1           1       A non-edit non-edit
# 2           1       B non-edit non-edit
# 3           1       C non-edit non-edit
# 4           1    open     edit     edit
# 5           1       A     edit     edit
# 6           1       J     edit     edit
# 7           1       M     edit     edit
# 8           1       K     edit     edit
# 9           1    exit     edit     edit
# 10          1       D non-edit non-edit
# 11          2    open     edit     edit
# 12          2       U     edit     edit
# 13          2       T     edit     edit
# 14          2    quit     edit     edit
# 15          2       I non-edit non-edit
# 16          2       M non-edit non-edit
# 17          2       A non-edit non-edit
# 18          3       Q non-edit non-edit
# 19          3       M non-edit non-edit
```